Как получить текст консоли Python
Хочу сделать анимацию падения текста. Но для этого нужно получить текст консоли до запуска программы. То есть на скрине программа должна получить текст:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.
C:\Users\HP>test.py
b'
C:\Users\HP>

Как я могу это провернуть? Может есть файл где хранится текст консоли(маловероятно). Помогите пожалуйста.
P.S: Может можно сохранить текст cmd в файл?

А зачем вам это, можете как-то подробнее рассказать о своей задаче?

Смотрите, я что-то делаю в консоли(cmd обычная к примеру), и запускаю из консоли программу. Это программа делает анимацию с текстом консоли. На данный момент моя проблема - я не могу получить текст из консоли как на примере

Проще тогда из самого скрипта через subprocess запустить консоль и уже читать из неё вывод. Наоборот вряли получится. Скрипт запущенный из консоли не будет иметь доступа к ранее введенному и выведенному в консоль. Можно еще повершел рассмотреть, там насколько помню есть файл ранее  введенных команд.

Считать текст, который уже был в консоли, по моему мнению, нельзя. Сама по себе задачка весьма специфична, так как подразумевает запуск скрипта из консоли. Практическое применение таких программ сомнительно. Однако можно таки считывать текст, который вводится пользователем в консоли после запуска вот такого скрипта. Это не решение, но технология может как-то пригодиться:
import sys

print("Введите текст и нажмите Enter. Для завершения считывания нажмите Ctrl+D или Ctrl+Z (Windows) и опять Enter.")
input_text = sys.stdin.read()
print("Вы ввели:")
print(input_text)


Увы, не то. Да и технология уже известная
